# Solr, Lucene e ElasticSearch quais as diferenças? Quando usar um ou outro?

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, elasticsearch, lucene, apache-solr

Qual a diferença entre ElasticSearch, Solr e Lucene?

Quando usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você deve saber que ambos servem para fazer buscas em conteúdos diversos.

## Lucene

Lucene está em um nível mais baixo. Por isso dá mais flexibilidade e ajuste fino do que deseja fazer. Por outro lado, você tem que saber fazer tudo o que precisa, dá mais trabalho. Costuma ser interessante quando quer embutir a busca dentro da sua aplicação e processá-la como quiser.

## Solr

Solr é uma abstração construída em cima do Lucene e é bem mais fácil de usar, com quase tudo pronto. Ainda é possível ter bastante flexibilidade, mas para isso dá mais trabalho e tem algumas limitações, dá menos trabalho fazer o padrão dele. Ele atende a maioria das situações já que é mais ou menos raro precisar fazer algo diferente do que ele oferece.

Existe uma infraestrutura mais ampla oferecida por esta ferramenta. Isto inclui serviços HTTP que permitem usar a busca até mesmo sem usar a API na linguagem de programação (Java por exemplo) e sim consumir o serviço pronto pela web.

Alguns recursos disponíveis:

- API HTTP trocando dados com XML/JSON
- Filtragem e busca dirigida (auxiliadores de busca como sugestão)
- Busca geoespacial
- Atualização incremental
- Cache
- Distribuição e replicação de dados
- Replicação de índice
- Painel administrativo.

Note que versões mais recentes do Lucene já possuem muitos dos recursos do Solr e está cada vez mais diminuindo a distância entre eles. Mas ainda há a diferença de como o serviço é oferecido.

## Elastic Search

O Elastic Search é um concorrente do Solr. Ele é considerado mais moderno por muitos e de fato tem mais facilidades que o Solr, tem um modelo que atende melhor muitas necessidades, principalmente de distribuição (o que é raro precisar) e atualização próxima do tempo real. Não dá para dizer que ele é mais adequado que o Solr sempre, até porque ele tem algumas limitações também, o modelo dele pode dificultar certas necessidades. E dizem ser ainda mais fácil trabalhar com ele.

Tem um [site que faz uma comparação entre eles](http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/) (que são mais comparáveis diretamente).

## Funcionalidade e escala

Um erro comum é as pessoas acharem que todo mundo precisa da solução mais escalável possível. Não, você não é o Facebook. Ou mesmo a Stack Exchange que é absurdamente menor. Quando eu falo que o SQLite está bom para 90% dos casos e um servidor SQL resolve 99% que tenha *full text search*, tem gente que não acredita.

Estes mecanismos são ótimos e algumas coisas prontas deles são bem interessantes, mas raramente precisa-se de algo além do trivial, especialmente quando falamos de escala.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Hummmm... O Solr usa o Lucene. E o Lucene posso usar numa aplicação desktop por exemplo? O Solr serviria para uma aplicação web mais robusta?

Comment: E o ElasticSearch, vi que usa o Lucene também. E é usado por sites como Netflix, Foursquare e o StackExchange.

Comment: A ideia é esta mesmo. Claro que você pode usar o Solr em uma aplicação desktop mas de um jeito não tradicional, não recomendado na maioria dos casos. O Solr pode ser considera a aplicação web. Em geral é usado de uma forma que ele seja um serviço independente mesmo que inserido em um site. O Lucente pode ser usado para isto também, mas você tem que cuidar de tudo. O ES também usa e hoje algumas pessoas preferem usá-lo. Não falei nada porque não está na pergunta. Ainda dá para editar se achar que deve incluí-lo. Eu edito depois se for o caso.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown. Muito esclarecedora a resposta. Creio que será útil para muitos programadores da comunidade da língua portuguesa.