# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar uma coluna VARCHAR como chave de índice?

Tags: banco-de-dados, otimização, índices, varchar

Tem desvantagens em usar uma coluna qualquer com tamanho variável, `VARCHAR` por exemplo, em um índice para uma tabela de um banco de dados? Faz diferença se for chave primária ou não? Ela ainda seria uma boa candidata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar algo de tamanho variável geralmente não causa problemas. Pode ter algum problema específico quando junta com outra coluna, mas é mais pelos dados, vou falar mais depois.

A grande vantagem do `VARCHAR` que você precisa, é otimizar o acesso em uma coluna assim, então tem que usar. Não sei se tem alguma vantagem mais específica.

Embora tenha algumas desvantagens, se precisa, não tem o que fazer. Tem algumas técnicas que podem minimizar as desvantagens.

Claro que é mais eficiente indexar colunas com números ou até com caracteres com tamanho fixo, mesmo um `VARCHAR` que na prática não muda de tamanho.

Talvez o maior problema do `VARCHAR` é que ele pode ser muito grande. Índices com chaves grandes afetam muito a performance geral de acesso, não só porque a comparação passa ser bem mais custosa que um objeto simples, mas também porque enche muito o cache e com isso consegue cachear bem menos objetos, o que obriga acessar outro nível de armazenamento mais caro. E organizar as [páginas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/582172/101) fica extremamente mais caro.

Alguns sistemas têm problemas ou até não permitem chaves muito grandes.

Em alguns casos você pode fazer um corte e pegar só o começo da *string*, mas nem sempre isso é possível de acordo com a sua necessidade. E tem casos que é melhor usar um índice para [*Full Text Search*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191573/101), que é até uma forma mais moderna e de melhor UX para acessar dados descritivos que o usuário precise. Em alguns casos até algum [mecanismo mais sofisticado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86854/101).

Esse tipo de índice pode não ser tão bom porque se o usuário tem que digitar o dado para achar é comum errar e não achar. Mais um motivo para usar outra forma de busca nesse tipo de dados.

Também pode ter problemas em alguns casos com alinhamento, especialmente quando tem dígitos numéricos no texto. "2" é maior que "10". É uma preocupação extra. Mas não por causa do tipo, é sobre o dado que está nele. O mesmo pode ser dito de ter o mesmo conteúdo visível, mas ter espaço(s) no final e o conteúdo ser diferente, que também tem solução.

Para chave primária, cai na mesma questão, depende mais do dado. Geralmente é estranho ter algo assim. Um `CHAR` pode ser bem normal, muito eventualmente até longo, mas um `VARCHAR` precisa de muita justificativa. Minha maior preocupação é que ela provavelmente será uma [chave natural, e isso pode ser um problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101).

Uma vantagem colateral pode ser que o dado tenha uma boa distribuição, quem sabe todas as chaves sejam únicas, e isso é muito bom para índices. Mas isso depende muito. Fica um contraste de códigos ou textos de tamanho fixo que tendem ter poucos valores diferentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).